# Linear regression using two different classes of basis functions

Tags: regression, basis-function

Let's say we have 1D data $Y = \{ y_i \mid y_i \in \mathbb{R} \}$, and regressors $X = \{ x_i \mid x_i \in \mathbb{R} \}$, and we try doing basis regression.

Suppose we find that we can perfectly describe $Y$ as being linear with respect to two different classes of basis functions: $Y = \Phi_1(X)\beta_1$ and $Y = \Phi_2(X)\beta_2$. (For a concrete example, suppose $\Phi_1(X) \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times K}$ comes from the responses of $K$ radial basis functions, while $\Phi_2(X) \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times K}$ is from $K$ cosine basis functions.)

Can we conclude anything about $\Phi_1(X)$ and $\Phi_2(X)$? I wouldn't have thought so, but empirically, it seems like you can write $\Phi_1(X) \approx \Phi_2(X) A + \mu$, with $A \in \mathbb{R}^{K \times K}$. In other words, the bases are linear transformations of one another.

Is this always true? This seems to suggest that if you can write some signal $y$ as being linear in some feature space, there is only one such feature space (up to linear transformations). Counterexamples would be very helpful!

Comment: All you can conclude is that a given point (namely $Y$) is in both the column span of $\Phi_1(X)$ and the column span of $\Phi_2(X)$. OK, so we have two (linear) sets, and there exists a point they have in common. We cannot conclude the sets are linear transformations of each other.

Comment: Thanks, I see that now! (I think part of my issue was that, when simulating, the different basis functions I was choosing were not as orthogonal to one another as I was assuming.)

Comment: What you *can* conclude is that when *all* $Y$ of the form $\Phi_1(X)\beta$ can be expressed as linear combinations of $\Phi_2(X),$ then $\Phi_1(X)$ is a linear transformation of $\Phi_2(X).$  (But that's a trivial observation...)

Answer (score 2):

I do not have enough reputation for a comment, so I make an answer.

I think you have an easy counter-example with $ X= y$ and $\Phi_i$ as the identity in the first coordinate and whatever else on other coordinates, taking $\beta_1 = \beta_2 = (1, 0, ..., 0)$

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply! Sorry, I realized there was a mis-specification in my original post. The regressors $X$ are also 1D, it's only K-dimensional in the basis space.

Comment: This does not change anything I suppose, I edited my answer

Comment: Ah, I see. I don't think "whatever else" is quite enough, but I get the idea, thank you! You specifically need the remaining bases in $\Phi_1$ and $\Phi_2$ to be orthogonal to each other. So a specific example would be $y = \cos(X)$, $\Phi_1(X) = [\cos(X); \cos(2X)]$ and $\Phi_2(X) = [\cos(X); \sin(X)]$.

Comment: If you could update your answer to reflect that I'll accept it. Thanks again!

Comment: Why $\Phi_1$ and $\Phi_2$ should be orthogonal ? Following your example, if $\Psi_i(X) = [\cos(X), f_i(X)]$ and $\beta_1 = \beta_2 = (1, 0)$ ?

Comment: If they are not orthogonal to one another, then you will be able to write one as a linear combination of the other trivially (i.e., regardless of whether or not they explain $y$)

Comment: My original question was whether you can write $\Phi_1(X)$ as an affine transformation of $\Phi_2(X)$. If $\Phi_1(X) = [cos(X); sin(X)]$ and $\Phi_2(X) = [cos(X); sin(X)]$ you can do this regardless of what $y$ is.

Comment: @mobeets: I edited my answer, I hope now is more clear. Or do you intended all $\beta_i$ coordinates be non-zero ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137936/discussion-between-mobeets-and-ohibo).